# How to activate the "Logback setup" debug mode using groovy configuration file?

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-groovy

I would like to activate the logback internal devbug mode (to get more information during the logback setup).

I know how to do this in xml file (using a debug="true" in the configuration declaration).
I discovered that it could be possible to force the flag using a system property (but I didn't achieved that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've seen this comment in the GafferConfigurator.groovy :
`// For now, Groovy/Gaffer configuration DSL does not support "debug" attribute. But in order to keep
// the conditional logic identical to that in XML/Joran, we have this empty block.`

So we can conclude it's not yet implemented...

Answer (score 0):

In logback.groovy you can set the level; by default it's set to "ERROR" in the logger() call.

Comment: My question was about the debug level for the internal setup of Logback. I'm not sure your answer was about that. Or I misunderstood you and I am interested in having more information about the solution.